# Issues with loading bitmaps with Picasso library in onPostExecute()

Tags: android, performance, android-asynctask, picasso, android-bitmap

I've got a problem loading bitmaps with Picasso in a loop. I'm loading them in AsyncTasks onPostExecute(). I know that i need global Target variables to prevent them from being collected by GC. Still none of my bitmaps are loaded. Here's my code:

```
private static Map<Integer, Bitmap> markerBitmaps;
private String[] markerUrls;
private Integer[] catIds;

//some code

private final static List<Target> targets = new ArrayList<Target>();
  @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        final int[] id = new int[1];
        int counter = 0;
        for(String s : markerUrls) {

                id[0] = catIds[counter];
            Target target = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
                    targets.remove(this);
                    markerBitmaps.put(id[0], bitmap);
                }
                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
                    targets.remove(this);
                }
                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
                }
            };

            Log.i("BITMAP URL IS:", s);
            targets.add(target);
            Picasso.with(MapsMenuActivity.this)
                    .load(s)// Start loading the current target
                    .into(target);
            counter++;
        }

        Log.i("BITMAPS NUM: ", String.valueOf(markerBitmaps.size()));
    }
```

The size of my markerBitmaps map is always 0.

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to do. Also, why use an AsyncTask if you do a lot of the work in the main thread (`onPostExecute`).

Comment: @Martin Marconcini  I'm trying to load bitmaps using Picasso library. Once it's loaded, i put in a HashMap. This method  must be called on main thread   Picasso.with(MapsMenuActivity.this)
                    .load(s)